# GnuPG encrypt a file using keys provided as files

Tags: encryption, gnupg, decryption, gpg4win

I'm using GPG4Win to create a key pair.
I'd like to be able to encrypt/decrypt a given file using myself as recipient so that I use exported key pair alone.

I want to be able to do this from a batch (.bat) file.

In general what are common steps used to encrypt/decrypt files using an exported key pair with commandline GPG?

Comment: This is not security related question, but a tools usage issues.
Anyway, check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305319/batch-encrypt-with-public-key-using-gpg4win-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use GPG with single key pair with `--default-recipient-self` argument.